# Race pausing a group of goroutines

Tags: go, synchronization, channel

I have a bunch of goroutines doing something in a loop. I want to be able to pause all of them, run some arbitrary code, then resume them. The way I attempted to do this is probably not idiomatic (and I'd appreciate a better solution), but I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Stripped down to the essentials (driver code at the bottom):

```
type looper struct {
    pause  chan struct{}
    paused sync.WaitGroup
    resume chan struct{}
}

func (l *looper) loop() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-l.pause:
            l.paused.Done()
            <-l.resume
        default:
            dostuff()
        }
    }
}

func (l *looper) whilePaused(fn func()) {
    l.paused.Add(32)
    l.resume = make(chan struct{})
    close(l.pause)
    l.paused.Wait()
    fn()
    l.pause = make(chan struct{})
    close(l.resume)
}
```

I spin up 32 goroutines all running `loop()`, then call `whilePaused` 100 times in a row, and everything seems to work… but if I run it with `-race`, it tells me that there's a race on `l.resume` between writing it in `whilePaused` (`l.resume = make(chan struct{})`) and reading it in `loop` (`<-l.resume`).

I don't understand why this happens. According to [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7), that `close(l.pause)` should happen before the `<-l.pause` in every `loop` goroutine. This should mean the `make(chan struct{})` value is visible as the value of `l.resume` in all of those `loop` goroutines, in the same way the string `"hello world"` is visible as the value of `a` in the `f` goroutine in the docs example.

---

Some additional information that might be relevant:

- If I replace `l.resume` with an `unsafe.Pointer` and access the `chan struct{}` value with `atomic.LoadPointer` in `loop` and `atomic.StorePointer` in `whilePaused`, the race goes away. This seems to be providing the exact same acquire-release ordering that the channel is already supposed to provide?
- If I add a `time.Sleep(10 * time.Microsecond)` between the `l.paused.Done()` and `<-l.resume`, the program usually deadlocks after calling `fn` one or two times.
- If I add a `fmt.Printf(".")` instead, the program prints 28 `.`s, calls the first function, prints another 32 `.`s, then hangs (or, occasionally, calls the second function, then prints another 32 `.`s and hangs).

---

Here's the rest of my code, in case you want to run the whole thing:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

// looper code from above

var n int64    
func dostuff() {
    atomic.AddInt64(&n, 1)
}

func main() {
    l := &looper{
        pause: make(chan struct{}),
    }
    var init sync.WaitGroup
    init.Add(32)
    for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
        go func() {
            init.Done()
            l.loop()
        }()
    }
    init.Wait()
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        l.whilePaused(func() { fmt.Printf("%d ", i) })
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n%d\n", atomic.LoadInt64(&n))
}
```

Comment: Channels are kind of awkward for this pattern. This looks like the perfect candidate to use a [`sync.Condition`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond) instead.

Comment: @JimB Unless Go conditions are very different from POSIX/etc. conditions, they're also pretty awkward for a try-wait scenario, where you can't just block in `for !ready { c.Wait() }`. Also, in my real code that `case <-l.pause:` would be inside a `select` that I already need for other reasons, so to use a `Condition`, wouldn't I have to have a goroutine that waits on the condition and sends on a channel anyway?

Comment: yeah, the `sync.Cond` doesn't work as well if you need to select against that logical condition. I saw the repeating broadcast pattern and immediately jumped to a condition variable, but in practice I rarely use them either ;)

Comment: @JimB My first thought was a condition as well, but that’s because I’m more used to a C-style threadpool with a queue of task structs (or a Python/C#/etc. executor, where I’d just throw in a pause task with the resuming on a future callback). I’m sure there is a better channel-based idiom for what I’m trying to do, I’m just not sure what it is. (The fact that my WaitGroup has to know how many goroutines I have seems clunky…)

Comment: It's hard to make a recommendation without the full context of course, but you might try and rethink the overall pattern you're using here. A common pitfall is to treat goroutines like threads. Dispatching goroutines is quite fast, and there are often simpler patterns available when you treat them as being disposable, creating and destroying them on demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because after the thread does l.paused.Done(), the other thread is able to go around the loop and assign l.resume again

Here is sequence of operations

```
Looper thread    |    Pauser thread
------------------------------------
l.paused.Done()  |   
                 |   l.paused.Wait()
                 |   l.pause = make(chan struct{})
                 |   round the loop
                 |   l.paused.Add(numThreads)
<- l.resume      |   l.resume = make(chan struct{})   !!!RACE!!
```